# Why does my programm call the while loop just once ? (Atmel C)

Tags: c, avr, atmega, atmel

Please help. My program runs the while loop just once :(

I don't know what the problem is. I programmed the same thing as well in python and there it worked fine.

I am a beginner in C and I am using the AtMega8 Microprocessor from Atmel.

```
#define F_CPU 8000000UL

#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

int main(void) {
    DDRD = 0xFF;
    int world[9];
    int nextworld[9];
    //from 1 to 8
    //some random start values  

    world[1] = 1;
    world[2] = 1;
    world[3] = 1;
    world[6] = 1;
    world[7] = 1;
    world[8] = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        nextworld[i] = world[i];
    }
    int binworld = 0;
    int tiles = 0;
    //=============================
    if (world[1] == 1) {
        binworld = binworld + 128;
    }
    if (world[2] == 1) {
        binworld = binworld + 64;
    }
    if (world[3] == 1) {
        binworld = binworld + 32;
    }
    if (world[4] == 1) {
        binworld = binworld + 16;
    }
    if (world[5] == 1) {
        binworld = binworld + 8;
    }
    if (world[6] == 1) {
        binworld = binworld + 4;
    }
    if (world[7] == 1) {
        binworld = binworld + 2;
    }
    if (world[8] == 1) {
        binworld = binworld + 1;
    }
    PORTD = binworld;
    //================================
    while (1) {
        _delay_ms(100);
        tiles = 0;
        //the live starts

        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            tiles = 0;
            for (int xc = -1; xc <= 1; xc++) {
                if (world[i + xc] == 1) {
                    tiles += 1;
                }

                if (world[i] == 1) {
                    tiles = tiles - 1;
                }
            }
            if (world[i] == 1 && tiles == 0) {
                nextworld[i] = 0;
            }
            else if (world[i] == 0 && tiles == 1) {
                nextworld[i] = 1;
            }
            else if (world[i] == 1 && tiles == 2) {
                nextworld[i] = 0;
            }   
        }
        //update old world
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            world[i] = nextworld[i];
        }

        //set null
        binworld = 0;
        //convert
        if (world[1] == 1) {
            binworld = binworld + 128;
        }
        if (world[2] == 1) {
            binworld = binworld + 64;
        }
        if (world[3] == 1) {
            binworld = binworld + 32;
        }
        if (world[4] == 1) {
            binworld = binworld + 16;
        }
        if (world[5] == 1) {
            binworld = binworld + 8;
        }
        if (world[6] == 1) {
            binworld = binworld + 4;
        }
        if (world[7] == 1) {
            binworld = binworld + 2;
        }
        if (world[8] == 1) {
            binworld = binworld + 1;
        }

        PORTD = binworld;
    }
}
```

Comment: Debugger.............

Comment: I take it the program is exiting before it finishes the while loop (it likely gives you an error on the command line).   You should post those kinds of details in your question.   I would start by either using a debugger, or putting some prints before and after the line that @500 pointed out.

Comment: Please note that "runs the while loop just once" is not something you directly observed, it is likely to be something you inferred by looking at the outputs of the AVR as it ran.  The things you inferred about your system are way less reliable than what you actually *observed*.  You should say what you observed, and what you expected to observe, and how your system is wired up.

Comment: It would also be great to indent your code properly and trim it down to a [mcve].

Comment: What is the value of `world[0]` in `for (int i=0;i<9;i++)

{
    nextworld[i]=world[i];
}` ?

Comment: World[0] and World[9] are just empty fields to prevent that negative index in the for loop for checking the current field's neighbours.

Comment: Thank you :) I just have the avr compiler installed so its hard to debug it.

Comment: I am trying to make a cellular automata in a 8 bit field in 1 dimension. I want to realize is in hardware

Answer (score 5):

Maybe because the array index is negative on the first iteration

```
for (int i=0; i<9;i++)
    {
        tiles = 0;
        for (int xc=-1; xc <= 1; xc++)
        {
            if (world[i+xc]==1) <== HERE, i(0) + xc(-1) == -1
```